# Update live AWS Sagemaker auto scaled endpoint instance type without putting it down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have one live AWS Sagemaker endpoint where we have auto scaled enabled. 
Now I want to updated it from 'ml.t2.xlarge' to 'ml.t2.2xlarge' but it is showing this error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the 
UpdateEndpoint operation: The variant(s) "[config1]" must be deregistered as scalable targets with 
Application Auto Scaling before they can be removed or have their instance type updated.
```

I believe we need to first de-register auto-scaling using this link 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/endpoint-auto-scaling-delete.html

but I doubt if will take our application down and the new model with training will take multiple hours. We can't afford this so please let me know if there are any better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no problem updating your Endpoint instance type without taking the availability hit. The basic method looks like this when you have an active autoscaling policy:

1. Create a new EndpointConfig that uses the new instance type, `ml.t2.2xlarge`

   1. Do this by calling [`CreateEndpointConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html).
   2. Pass in the same values you used for your previous Endpoint config. You can point to the same `ModelName` that you did as well. By reusing the same model, you don't have to retrain it or anything
2. [Delete the existing autoscaling policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/endpoint-auto-scaling-delete.html)

   1. Depending on your autoscaling, you might want to increase the desired count of your Endpoint in the event it needs to scale while you are doing this.
   2. If you are experience a spike in traffic while you are making these API calls, you risk an outage of your model if it can't keep up with traffic. Just keep this in mind and possibly scale in advance for this possibility.
3. Call `UpdateEndpoint` like you did previously and specify this new `EndpointConfigName`
4. Wait for your Endpoint status to be `InService`. This should take 10-20 mins.
5. [Create a new autoscaling policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/endpoint-auto-scaling-add-policy.html) for this new Endpoint and production variant

You should be good to go without sacrificing availability.

Comment: When the endpoint status is "Updating' for the 10-20mins you mentioned, is it still going to handle inference requests to it?